# Rechart draw lines for mutiple sets of data

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Say, I have two arrays of data, A and B.

```
A = [
{name:'Mon Oct 24 2022 17:00:00', value: 1},
{name:'Mon Oct 24 2022 18:00:00', value: 2},
{name:'Mon Oct 24 2022 19:00:00', value: 3},
{name:'Mon Oct 24 2022 20:00:00', value: 4}
]
```

and

```
B = [
{name:'Mon Oct 24 2022 17:30:00', value: 5},
{name:'Mon Oct 24 2022 18:30:00', value: 4},
{name:'Mon Oct 24 2022 19:30:00', value: 3},
]
```

Now I want to draw two lines with different colours for these data in the same line chart with the correct x-axis, e.g. `B[0]` is in the middle of `A[0]` and `A[1]`. But I couldn't make it work, it's always the case that the line for `B` comes after the line for `A` the line.
It would be better if the x-axis uses `[0, 'auto']` as the `domain` property.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Solve it. Conver time string to stamp, and make Axis `type` be `number`.